# How to use gin indexes in postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql, indexing

I have never used GIN indexing before and I am trying to understand how it works.
I have a static table with 4million rows, which I need to run SELECT queries with WHERE clauses.

Right now my table has a B-Tree index on the column "name" which is used in the where clause.

I have read that doing a full text search using a GIN index can greatly improve the speed. I have read the tutorial [here](https://blog.lateral.io/2015/05/full-text-search-in-milliseconds-with-postgresql/) and right now I am not sure if this is something I can use when I have only one table.

Does full text search works in case of multiple tables that we want to join?

I understand that the GIN Indexing works on a tsvector column. This is what I have done till now:

I have altered my table and added one more column: tsv:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN tsv tsvector;
```

I createad a GIN index on my ts_vector column:

```
CREATE INDEX tsv_idx ON my_table USING gin(to_tsvector('english', name));
```

And I have updated the column:

```
UPDATE my_table SET tsv = to_tsvector(name)
```

Are the above correct? So now if I want to run the following query:

```
SELECT clm1, clmn2 FROM my_table WHERE name LIKE 'Ath%' ORDER BY 1
```

how can I do it using the GIN index?

I tried this:

```
SELECT clm1, clmn2 FROM my_table WHERE tvs LIKE 'Ath%' ORDER BY 1
```

But I get an error:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: tsvector ~~ unknown
```

What am I missing here? What is the correct use of GIN? And can I apply full text search on a single table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to index for what you want to query.  A tsvector doesn't help you with a `like` search.  Since that is a prefix though, a standard btree would work.  If you want to do an infix search (`where mycol like '%something%'`) you need to use pg_trgm extension and make a trigram GIN index.

Pay close attention to what to_tsvector returns and note that is what you are indexing.  What you are indexing doesn't give your query anything.

Comment: Thanks. After all I used the pg_trgm extension together with the GIN index. I have created the index as: CREATE INDEX my_index ON my_table USING gin (name COLLATE pg_catalog."default" gin_trgm_ops);  Using the EXPLAIN command made sure that the index is used and there was significan improvement in the speed.

Comment: Now I am trying to figure out other ways to speed things up. E.g. materialized views or server side cursors (as i use psycopg2).